# Java Open a new window by clicking a button

Tags: java, swing, button

Been sitting here at my computer for about 13 hours and I think my eyes are bleeding.
I found a little gui editor I love called GuiGenie.
It works perfect for creating the window with the buttons and all that good stuff.
The problem is i want to click a button in my first menu and have it open my other menu i made.
I just starting programming 4 weeks ago so I'm a complete noob.
I have a feeling its messing up because of the main methods but I have no idea and 13 hours of sitting here trying millions of things is making me go crazy  : )
here is what i got so far

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import javax.swing.event.*;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
private JTextField How;
private JLabel jcomp2;
private JLabel jcomp3;
private JButton jcomp4;

public MyPanel() {
    //construct components
    How = new JTextField (1);
    jcomp2 = new JLabel ("How long were you parked?");
    jcomp3 = new JLabel ("Minutes");
    jcomp4 = new JButton ("openNewWindow");

    //adjust size and set layout
    setPreferredSize (new Dimension (315, 85));
    setLayout (null);

    //add components
    add (How);
    add (jcomp2);
    add (jcomp3);
    add (jcomp4);

    //set component bounds (only needed by Absolute Positioning)
    How.setBounds (245, 50, 60, 25);
    jcomp2.setBounds (35, 30, 185, 50);
    jcomp3.setBounds (250, 30, 60, 20);
    jcomp4.setBounds (0, 0, 315, 25);

       jcomp4.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

        }
    });
}


public static void main (String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("MyPanel");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add (new MyPanel());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible (true);
}
}
```

When the button is pressed, I want it to open this new window

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class MyPanel2 extends JPanel {
private JButton jcomp1;
private JButton jcomp2;
private JButton jcomp3;
private JTextField jcomp4;

public MyPanel2() {
    //construct components
    jcomp1 = new JButton ("test1");
    jcomp2 = new JButton ("test2");
    jcomp3 = new JButton ("test3");
    jcomp4 = new JTextField (5);

    //adjust size and set layout
    setPreferredSize (new Dimension (395, 156));
    setLayout (null);

    //add components
    add (jcomp1);
    add (jcomp2);
    add (jcomp3);
    add (jcomp4);

    //set component bounds (only needed by Absolute Positioning)
    jcomp1.setBounds (20, 45, 100, 25);
    jcomp2.setBounds (135, 60, 100, 25);
    jcomp3.setBounds (260, 35, 100, 25);
    jcomp4.setBounds (105, 115, 100, 25);
}


public static void main (String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("MyPanel");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add (new MyPanel2());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible (true);
}
}
```

If anyone could help I would appreciate it greatly!!
I have a lot of respect for you pros out there because if you are a pro at this, you are probably smarter than 99.9%  of the world.
This stuff hurts my brain.

Comment: Stop trying random things, take a break, sleep a good night, and then read the Swing tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/. Understand that a JPanel must be enclosed in a JFrame of JDialog to be shown in a new window, and that you should only have one main method in an application. You don't need two.

Answer (score 8):

Here is something you can do, for this situation, where you have multiple `Forms or Windows` what you can do is to use a `JPanel` which can have this [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) set as it's `LayoutManager` and then you can add the two `JPanel`s to it and access them with the methods provided by the same.

Don't use `setBounds()` when using `Absolute Positioning` this is really not the right way of putting components to the parent container. Instead use [setLocation(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setLocation%28int,%20int%29) and [setSize(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setSize%28int,%20int%29) methods. Consider not to use Absolute Positioning as much as possible for you. Certain lines in favour of the before said line taken from Java Docs are as follows :

> Although it is possible to do without a layout manager, you should use a 
>       layout manager if at all possible. A layout manager makes it easier to 
>       adjust to look-and-feel-dependent component appearances, to different 
>       font sizes, to a container's changing size, and to different locales. 
>       Layout managers also can be reused easily by other containers, as well as 
>       other programs.

Since the output of your program is really not a soothing experience in any sense. Atleast LayoutManager, can make that work a lot more easier for you, since you need not have to specify position and size for each and every component. Try walking through the [Layout Mangers Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), and get accustomed to them as soon as possible. They are the real life savers :-)

Here is a modified code taken from your `SOURCE CODE`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CardLayoutExample
{
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private MyPanel panel1;
    private MyPanel2 panel2;

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Card Layout Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new CardLayout());
        panel1 = new MyPanel(contentPane);
        panel2 = new MyPanel2();
        contentPane.add(panel1, "Panel 1"); 
        contentPane.add(panel2, "Panel 2");
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();   
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new CardLayoutExample().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private JTextField How;
    private JLabel jcomp2;
    private JLabel jcomp3;
    private JButton jcomp4;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    public MyPanel(JPanel panel) {

        contentPane = panel;
        //construct components
        How = new JTextField (1);
        jcomp2 = new JLabel ("How long were you parked?");
        jcomp3 = new JLabel ("Minutes");
        jcomp4 = new JButton ("openNewWindow");

        //adjust size and set layout
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension (315, 85));
        setLayout (null);

        //set component bounds (only needed by Absolute Positioning)
        How.setBounds (245, 50, 60, 25);
        jcomp2.setBounds (35, 30, 185, 50);
        jcomp3.setBounds (250, 30, 60, 20);
        jcomp4.setLocation(0, 0);
        jcomp4.setSize(315, 25);
        jcomp4.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) contentPane.getLayout();
                cardLayout.next(contentPane);
            }
        });

        //add components
        add (How);
        add (jcomp2);
        add (jcomp3);
        add (jcomp4);               
    }
}

class MyPanel2 extends JPanel {
    private JButton jcomp1;
    private JButton jcomp2;
    private JButton jcomp3;
    private JTextField jcomp4;

    public MyPanel2() {
        //construct components
        jcomp1 = new JButton ("test1");
        jcomp2 = new JButton ("test2");
        jcomp3 = new JButton ("test3");
        jcomp4 = new JTextField (5);

        //adjust size and set layout
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension (395, 156));
        setLayout (null);

        //set component bounds (only needed by Absolute Positioning)
        jcomp1.setBounds (20, 45, 100, 25);
        jcomp2.setBounds (135, 60, 100, 25);
        jcomp3.setBounds (260, 35, 100, 25);
        jcomp4.setBounds (105, 115, 100, 25);

        //add components
        add (jcomp1);
        add (jcomp2);
        add (jcomp3);
        add (jcomp4);       
    }
}
```

Comment: Useful example, but you should guide the OP _away_ from using `null` layout. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code for myPanel class, use this one:

```
import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

 import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
private JTextField How;
private JLabel jcomp2;
private JLabel jcomp3;
private JButton jcomp4;

public MyPanel() {
    //construct components
    How = new JTextField (1);
    jcomp2 = new JLabel ("How long were you parked?");
    jcomp3 = new JLabel ("Minutes");
    jcomp4 = new JButton ("openNewWindow");

    jcomp4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame ("MyPanel");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add (new MyPanel2());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible (true);

        }
    });

    //adjust size and set layout
    setPreferredSize (new Dimension (315, 85));
    setLayout (null);

    //add components
    add (How);
    add (jcomp2);
    add (jcomp3);
    add (jcomp4);

    //set component bounds (only needed by Absolute Positioning)
    How.setBounds (245, 50, 60, 25);
    jcomp2.setBounds (35, 30, 185, 50);
    jcomp3.setBounds (250, 30, 60, 20);
    jcomp4.setBounds (0, 0, 315, 25);

       jcomp4.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

        }
    });
}


public static void main (String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("MyPanel");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add (new MyPanel());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible (true);
}
}
```

Comment: Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).