# How to create new and dispose jcomponents multiple times?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener, jcomponent

*(Sorry if this question is not done properly, I'm new. But at least I researched a lot before asking my own question)*

Hello. I'm writing a blackjack game in java and it's turning quite massive. **My problem** is how to handle multiple instances of swing components, I guess you can call it. I can't figure out wether to create the components (such as jpanels and jbuttons) as class level, or in specific methods.

If I create them in their corresponding method, then my action listener can't see them, but if I create them as class level, then they get deleted when I call `dispose()`.

```
 class BlackjackGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    public void mainMenu(){

        JPanel menuPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); //Init of main menu
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        menuPane.setBackground(new Color(125,0,0));
        menuPane.setBounds(620,220,175,250);

        JLabel menuTitle = new JLabel("Welcome to Blackjack!");//Main menu-content
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,0,20,0);
        menuPane.add(menuTitle, c);

        JButton playButton = new JButton("Play!");
        playButton.addActionListener(this);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.ipadx = 25;
        c.ipady = 25;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        menuPane.add(playButton, c);

        JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit!");
        exitButton.addActionListener(this);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        menuPane.add(exitButton, c);

        JButton rulesButton = new JButton("Set rules.");
        rulesButton.addActionListener(this);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        menuPane.add(rulesButton, c);

        this.add(menuPane,0);
    }

    //This is where I get problems
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
        if(event.getSource() == playButton){
            //I want the menuPane to disappear, and a transition into the game.
            menuPane.dispose();
            //Call method for the rest of the game.

        }else if(event .getSource() etcetera etcetera){
            etcetera etcetera
        }
    }
}
```

When done this way, the actionlistener cannot find my components, such as playButton or menuPane. But if I had introduced them as class level objects:

```
class BlackjackGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JPanel menuPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JLabel menuTitle = new JLabel("Welcome to Blackjack!");
    JButton playButton = new JButton("Play!");
    JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit!");
    JButton rulesButton = new JButton("Set rules.");

    public void mainMenu(){
        //Rest of code
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        menuPane.dispose();
        //Rest of code
    }
}
```

...then as I call `menuPane.dispose()`, how can I get it back when I want to call `mainMenu()` again? If I want to go back to the main menu, then I would need to create a new instance of menuPane, as well as all the buttons, but as they are class level and already disposed I can't.

Please help me, and thank you!

*PS. I can post my full code as it is atm if it would help.*

Edit: Dan's answer has been accepted, as it was indeed the correct answer and it worked for my specific program very well. Thank you and merry christmas!

Comment: i think you can get help from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273267/java-open-a-new-window-by-clicking-a-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, unless I've misunderstood your code, `menuPane.dispose()` shouldn't work as `JPanel` does not have a function called `dispose()`

The best way to do what you want to do if you want to use the same `menuPane` for the menu. Instead of `menuPane.dispose();` use `remove(menuPane);` and then `add(yourOtherPanel);`

**Working Example**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BlackjackGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JPanel menuPane;
    private JLabel menuTitle;
    private JButton playButton;
    private JButton exitButton;
    private JButton rulesButton;

    private JPanel otherPane;
    private JLabel otherTitle;
    private JButton otherButton;

    public BlackjackGame() {
        mainMenu();
        otherPanel();
        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void mainMenu() {

        menuPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        menuPane.setBackground(new Color(125,0,0));
        menuPane.setBounds(620,220,175,250);

        menuTitle = new JLabel("Welcome to Blackjack!");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,0,20,0);
        menuPane.add(menuTitle, c);

        playButton = new JButton("Play!");
        playButton.addActionListener(this);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.ipadx = 25;
        c.ipady = 25;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        menuPane.add(playButton, c);

        exitButton = new JButton("Exit!");
        exitButton.addActionListener(this);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        menuPane.add(exitButton, c);

        rulesButton = new JButton("Set rules.");
        rulesButton.addActionListener(this);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        menuPane.add(rulesButton, c);

        add(menuPane);
    }

    private void otherPanel() {
        otherPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        otherPane.setBackground(new Color(125,0,0));
        otherPane.setBounds(620,220,175,250);

        otherTitle = new JLabel("Welcome to Second Pane!");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,0,20,0);
        otherPane.add(otherTitle, c);

        otherButton = new JButton("Go Back!");
        otherButton.addActionListener(this);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.ipadx = 25;
        c.ipady = 25;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        otherPane.add(otherButton, c);
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
        if(event.getSource() == playButton) {
            remove(menuPane);
            add(otherPane);
            validate();
            repaint();

        } else if(event.getSource() == otherButton) {
            remove(otherPane);
            add(menuPane);
            validate();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new BlackjackGame());
    }
}
```

**Edit for comments**

So the java method [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#remove(java.awt.Component)) only removes the object from the container, which in this case is the `JFrame`. This method does not effect the object it moves so the object can be reused later. Hence why in the code above I can just use the `remove()` and `add()` methods without redeclaring or remaking `menuPane` and `otherPane`.

As for why I declare the objects like this

```
`private JPanel menuPane;`
```

And then initialize like this

```
menuPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
```

This is because I want the `ActionListener` to be able to see the objects without initializing them straight away. The line `private JPanel menuPane;` makes the object a global variable and the line `menuPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());` makes it into what I am going to use. Doing it this way instead of `JPanel menuPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());` also means I can reuse the same variable in multiple methods. For example

```
private JPanel panel;

private void createPanelOne() {
    panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    ...
    add(panel);
}

private void createPanelTwo() {
    panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    ...
    add(panel);
}
```

After doing this, you will have two `JPanel`s in your `JFrame` and they will be different, but you only need to use one `JPanel`

This is the other way of declaring it and it makes a local variable. Local variables aren't visible to other methods outside of the method you are using unless you pass them through.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
```

I wouldn't say this is a con in the slightest. I think sometimes it is good to use local variables in a method that shouldn't be visible to other methods.

Finally to pass local variables through to other methods you can use arguments in a method you have made. For example

```
public void setSomeValue(int val) {
    someValue = val;
}
```

Comment: Okey let me see if I've understood what you did. First in `public BlackjackGame()` you called both methods `mainMenu()` and `otherPanel()` to create the both instances of the two panes. Then you use `add()` and `remove()` to display/undisplay them when needed. This is where I seem to have misunderstood how it works, because will `remove()` not delete the pane, making it disappear, and if I want it to show again i need to re-initiate it? I.e. `menuPane = new JPanel();` Thanks for helping!

Comment: @heradsinn Of course. I will just edit my answer. Please wait two moments

Comment: Another thing, the way I learnt to initiate objects and components is `JPanel menuPane = new JPanel();`, while you first declare it `private JPanel menuPane;`, and then (without JPanel infront) `menuPane = new JPanel();`. Could you please explain the difference and pros/cons, thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think this is the solution to my problem! Back to coding :)

Comment: @heradsinn I'm glad this did help you, and you think the answer is satisfactorily correct, I hope I can ask you to accept my answer. Please read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more info on when and why you should accept an answer :)

Comment: @heradsinn Also welcome to stack overflow and merry Christmas